# New to Python... if statement confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

So I have this:

```
import math

g = int(input("Put a number here: "))
print ("Your number is: " + str(g))
c = int(input("Would you like to see your number's sqaure root? (Y/N"))
if c == "Y"
    print ("Your number squared is: " + str(math.sqrt(g)))
```

And it (PyScripter) says that 'if c == "Y"' is a syntax error. I am probably mixing up my data types or some other newbie mistake, but I can't figure out because the syntax seems to be consistent with other examples... an answer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you think `c = int(input ("..."))` would do?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! First take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and second at http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask .Next time you should double check your code before asking on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All blocks in Python, such as:
if
for
def
class

requires `:`

Examlpe

```
def your_function(string):
  for word in string.slpit():
    if word == 'Python':
      return word
    else:
      print 'No Python in string'
```

As you can see every block's line ends with **:**

Answer (score 4):

[You forgot the colon.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)

```
if ... :
```

Answer (score 0):

All block level statements in Python (those that have other statements indented), should end with a `:`.  You were missing the `:` after the if (which defines a block).

```
import math

g = int(input("Put a number here: "))
print ("Your number is: " + str(g))
c = int(input("Would you like to see your number's sqaure root? (Y/N"))
if c == "Y":
    print ("Your number squared is: " + str(math.sqrt(g)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `:` after the `if` statement.